# React native selectable text doesnt work on some xiaomi devices

Tags: java, react-native, text, coordinates, android-actionmode

I'm using react-native-selectable-text currently on my app and it's working with no issues on android devices except some xiaomi devices.İ tried to customize selection (e.g: Choose,add to favorite) but xiaomi devices still showing default selection [actions.](https://xiaomi.eu/community/attachments/33890/). Apart from this issue,i want to get Rect coordinates of selectedText. How can i do this? This code from RNSelectableTextManager.java of [react-native-selectanle-text.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@alentoma/react-native-selectable-text)

```
//RNSelectableTextManager.java
...
String selectedText = view.getText().toString().substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
...
```

İ read Xiaomi devices not responding to onPrepareActionMode, they are responding to onCreateActionMode on forum.Then i tried this code;

```
//RNSelectableTextManager.java
...
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                menu.clear();                                   //Added this line
                for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {    //Added this line
                  menu.add(0, i, 0, menuItems[i]);              //Added this line
                }                                               //Added this line
                return true;
            }
...
```

but still doesn't work.